# How could changing one instance would change all the other instances in NURBS-python / geomdl?

Tags: python

The code following would output curve images, I am expecting crv1 ,2, 3 would have different shape or at least different control points.

While look at the last image output, looks like by changing crv3, crv 1, and 2 are also changed, how could this be possible?

```
from geomdl import BSpline
from geomdl import multi
from geomdl.visualization import VisMPL

crv1 = BSpline.Curve()
crv1.degree = 2
crv1.ctrlpts = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]]
crv1.knotvector = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
crv1.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv1.render()

crv2=crv1
crv2.insert_knot(0.25)
crv2.insert_knot(0.5)
crv2.insert_knot(0.75)
crv2.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv2.render()

crv3=crv2
crv3.remove_knot(0.5)
crv3.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv3.render()

crv=multi.CurveContainer([crv1, crv2, crv3])
crv.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv.render()
```

Is this a bug or my misunderstanding? Please help out, thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes ... you set all three to refer to the same object.  Where is the confusion?

Comment: So it means I refer all together, this looks a little different from C++, right? The same behavior for all class object? then how should I get a copy of another instance instead of a link or a pointer?

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python copy class object", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `deepcopy` fits here:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from geomdl import BSpline
from geomdl import multi
from geomdl.visualization import VisMPL

crv1 = BSpline.Curve()
crv1.degree = 2
crv1.ctrlpts = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]]
crv1.knotvector = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
crv1.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv1.render()

crv2=deepcopy(crv1)  # changed
crv2.insert_knot(0.25)
crv2.insert_knot(0.5)
crv2.insert_knot(0.75)
crv2.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv2.render()

crv3=deepcopy(crv2)  # changed
crv3.remove_knot(0.5)
crv3.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv3.render()

crv=multi.CurveContainer([crv1, crv2, crv3])
crv.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
crv.render()
```